# is there a way to make elements with absolute position to take screen width?

Tags: html, css

I need for a moment to view long code with absolute positioned elements in a way where they scale proportionally to screen width.
Is there a way to wrap this code without changing anything in it?

[JS Fiddle demo with short example](http://jsfiddle.net/mmzJR/)

```
<div id="Table_01">
    <div id="id1-01">
        <img width="30" height="180">
    </div>...



 #Table_01 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:480px;
    height:180px;
}

#id1-01 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:30px;
    height:180px;
}...
```

Comment: Yea, it's possible.. http://jsfiddle.net/Snzcn/

Comment: sorry, but can I somehow overwrite the code in my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mmzJR/) - adding css or wraping it, so that I don't have to change it by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to change existing code, you can use percentages within more specific CSS rules:

```
div#Table_01 {
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
}

div#id1-01 {
    left:0;
    width:30%;
}

div#id1-02 {
    left:30%;
    width:20%;
}

div#id1-03 {
    left:50%;
    width:10%;
}

div#id1-04 {
    left:60%;
    width:20%;
}

div#id1-05 {
    left:80%;
    width:20%;
}
```

Comment: it won't work in this case since the original code is too long and complex. I thought maybe I can add some viewport meta tag or something...

Comment: You are going to have to be more clear, as this solves the given problem.

Comment: sorry but in the original question I asked "Is there a way to wrap this code without changing anything in it?" Sorry once again.

Comment: You could use percentages in CSS rules with more specificity (ie. div#Table_01) to override the existing CSS if you can't remove it. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `width: 100%;` property.

I've always been a fan of % over px anyway!